# Opening links in other windows with Javascript

Tags: javascript, window

I am beyond new to JavaScript. Having only just differentiated it from Java as a programming language, I have decided to take it up, and want to try out some practical projects. But I have no idea what I'm doing wrong in terms of why my code is just screwing up.

### The Idea

At work, I have a system where by simply opening a URL in my browser I can execute a script to reset a batch of ribbon screens. I don't know how the code works, but it does, and I'm happy. But I rather want to have a webpage I can go to that batch opens every webpage. It can be messy; at this point I only want the job done. So from what I understand, I've managed to cobble together some code.

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ribbon screen batch Reset</title>
<script>
var txt="Success!";
 function open()
 {
 try
   {
       window.open("test.html");
   document.write("<p>",txt,"</p><br />");
   }
 catch(err)
   {
   document.write("Something went wrong here.");
   document.write("Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n");
   alert("Interrupted due to errors. See webpage for details");
   }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
<h1>Ribbon screen batch reset Type 1 </h1>
<p>Version 1.0.3</p>
<button type="button" onclick="open()">Run code</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I promise you I can't see a problem, I have another document in the same folder called `test.html`, it's just when I click the button on `index.html` the button disappears, and I'm left with just a blank page. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: I know you have posted about Javascript, But have you looked at or heard of the jQuery Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple fixes:

1) `open` is a reserved word; call your function something else.

2)  You must name the window, then use that name to manipulate it.

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var txt="Success!";
             function openit()
             {
             try
               {
                    testwin = window.open("test.html");
                    testwin.document.write("<p>",txt,"</p><br />"); 
               }
             catch(err)
               {
                    document.write("Something went wrong here.");
                    document.write("Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n");
                    alert("Interrupted due to errors. See webpage for details");
               }
             }

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" />
    <h1>Ribbon screen batch reset Type 1 </h1>
    <p>Version 1.0.3</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="openit()">Run code</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @gibberish, this makes the most sense to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Rename your function to something else, like *openMyPage*. Using `onclick="open()"` will call [`document.open`](http://w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_open.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the "ribbon screen" is but your code has a lot of problems.
First, being if you are using `document.write()` in `<header>` the outcome is not going to be visible and it's overall bad practice.

Second problem is this is completely wrong `document.write("<p>",txt,"</p><br />");`
the correct code would be `document.write("<p>"+txt+"</p><br />");`

Third, is you can write this whole thing as just one short line:
`<button type="button" onclick="window.open("test.html")">Run code</button>`

Hope this helps,
Cheers

Comment: Please test your ideas before posting. Your first two comments are incorrect (the code I posted above works fine).